# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre IFNULL y COALESCE en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, null

Si tengo una tabla como esta:

```
id        valor
--------------------
1         NULL
2         2
3         3
```

Puedo usar indistintamente `COALESCE` o `IFNULL` si quiero sustituir los valores `NULL` por otra cosa.

#### `COALESCE`

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    COALESCE(valor,0) valor 
FROM mi_tabla;
```

#### `IFNULL`

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    IFNULL(valor,0) valor 
FROM mi_tabla;
```

En ambos casos el resultado es el mismo:

```
id       valor
-------------------
1        0  
2        2  
3        3
```

Entonces, ¿cuál es la diferencia entre `IFNULL` y `COALESCE`?, ¿por qué existen si hacen lo mismo, es porque en algunos casos conviene usar una u otra?

Comment: Hay pequeñas diferencias ,`COALESCE` admite mas de dos parámetros por ejemplo.

Comment: Expando con un par de enlaces (en ingles): https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqltips/2008/06/26/differences-between-isnull-and-coalesce/ y http://www.itprotoday.com/software-development/coalesce-vs-isnull

Comment: Gracias @Pikoh. Los enlaces habla de SQL Server, ¿todo lo dicho aplica también para MySQL?

Comment: Creo que si, aunque de MySql tengo menos conocimiento. `COALESCE` es ANSI SQL, con lo que estará disponible en todas las bases de datos.  `IFNULL` si no me equivoco se definió originalmente en en el standard T-SQL que es una extensión de microsoft al sql, pero creo que mysql lo implementa tambien. Lo que desconozco es si ambas implementaciones de `IFNULL` varían en algo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`IFNULL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html) es una función de control de flujo mientras que [`COALESCE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) es una funcion de comparacion.

`IFNULL` retorna el segundo parámetro si el primero es `NULL`:

```
SELECT IFNULL(NULL,'HOLA MUNDO'); // HOLA MUNDO
SELECT IFNULL('BUENAS', 'NOCHES'); // BUENAS
```

Mientras que `COALESCE` retorna el primer parametro que no sea NULL:

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULL, NULL, 'HOLA', NULL, 'MUNDO'); // HOLA
SELECT COALESCE(NULL, NULL, NULL, 'MUNDO', 'BUENAS'); // MUNDO
```

`COALESCE`, a diferencia de `IFNULL`, no tiene un limite en el numero de parámetros.